# Can't seem find the largest float in an array, using inline assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I have been tasked with doing some assembly work. All was going good, until I had to convert a program from using int to floats. I'm probably missing something simple in my attempts, but does anyone have a suggestion? I'll provide the int version which works.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int n;
int i;
int arr[50];
int output;

int main(void)
{
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    __asm
    {
        jmp start

        switching:
            mov eax, ebx
            jmp looping

        looping:
            mov ebx, arr[ecx*4]
            inc ecx
            cmp ebx, eax

            jg switching

            cmp ecx, n
            jl looping
            ret

        start:
            mov ecx, 0
            mov eax, 0

            call looping

            mov output, eax
    }

    printf("%d", output);
    scanf("%d", &n);
}
```

Comment: How are we supposed to help with the floats if you post the int version?

Comment: I just wanted a couple of pointers on if i would have to change any of the conditional opcodes when using floats.

Comment: If your floats are all non-negative, the assembly for finding the largest (single-precision) float and for finding the largest (32-bit) integer should be identical.

Comment: Thanks, I had been explicitly told that it would not work, so I didn't try that at first.

Comment: @R.. You COULD do it that way, but it doesn't mean it's right :)

Comment: This is asm. Anything that works is right. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to rewrite most of your solution. If you are new to floats and want to use x87, [here](http://www.website.masmforum.com/tutorials/fptute/) is a good guide to read.

To test floats you will need something like this conditional jump:

```
fld     <float to compare>
fcom    <maximum value>
fnstsw  ax
test    ah,$1
jnz     <notbigger>
```